# Get parts of mailto link in Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I have webview opened with a webpage containing mailto link (mailto:test@test.com)

I am able to get the `url=mailto:test@test.com` but not get the parts unlike a regular url. I want to extract the email from the mailto url to prefill while composing a message. Is there an elegant way to extract test@test.com from mailto url in Swift iOS?

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
 let request: URLRequest = navigationAction.request

        if let url = request.url,
            url.scheme == "mailto" {
            decisionHandler(.cancel)
            let urlString = "scheme://myapp/open/compose?\(url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "="))
            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: urlString)!)
            return
        }
}
```

Comment: What attempt did you make to get the parts of the mailto URL?

Comment: I modified the custom app url to accept mailto as parameter and tried this `let urlString = "scheme://myapp/open/compose?\(url.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: ":", with: "="))"`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can just get your url path component:

```
let url = URL(string: "mailto:test@test.com")!
if url.scheme == "mailto", 
    let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) {
    let email = components.path
    print(email)  // "test@test.com\n"
}
```

You can also extend URL as follow:

```
extension URL {
    var email: String? {
        return scheme == "mailto" ? URLComponents(url: self, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)?.path : nil
    }
}
```

---

```
if let email = url.email {
    print("email:", email)    // "email: test@test.com\n"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To complete @Leo Dabus's answer, I've written a comprehensive `struct` that handles all cases as specified in [RFC2368](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368):

```swift
struct EmailParameters {
    /// Guaranteed to be non-empty
    let toEmails: [String]
    let ccEmails: [String]
    let bccEmails: [String]
    let subject: String?
    let body: String?

    /// Defaults validation is just verifying that the email is not empty.
    static func defaultValidateEmail(_ email: String) -> Bool {
        return !email.isEmpty
    }

    /// Returns `nil` if `toEmails` contains at least one email address validated by `validateEmail`
    /// A "blank" email address is defined as an address that doesn't only contain whitespace and new lines characters, as defined by CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines
    /// `validateEmail`'s default implementation is `defaultValidateEmail`.
    init?(
        toEmails: [String],
        ccEmails: [String],
        bccEmails: [String],
        subject: String?,
        body: String?,
        validateEmail: (String) -> Bool = defaultValidateEmail
    ) {
        func parseEmails(_ emails: [String]) -> [String] {
            return emails.map { $0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) }.filter(validateEmail)
        }
        let toEmails = parseEmails(toEmails)
        let ccEmails = parseEmails(ccEmails)
        let bccEmails = parseEmails(bccEmails)
        if toEmails.isEmpty {
            return nil
        }
        self.toEmails = toEmails
        self.ccEmails = ccEmails
        self.bccEmails = bccEmails
        self.subject = subject
        self.body = body
    }

    /// Returns `nil` if `scheme` is not `mailto`, or if it couldn't find any `to` email addresses
    /// `validateEmail`'s default implementation is `defaultValidateEmail`.
    /// Reference: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2368
    init?(url: URL, validateEmail: (String) -> Bool = defaultValidateEmail) {
        guard let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false) else {
            return nil
        }
        let queryItems = urlComponents.queryItems ?? []
        func splitEmail(_ email: String) -> [String] {
            return email.split(separator: ",").map(String.init)
        }
        let initialParameters = (toEmails: urlComponents.path.isEmpty ? [] : splitEmail(urlComponents.path), subject: String?(nil), body: String?(nil), ccEmails: [String](), bccEmails: [String]())
        let emailParameters = queryItems.reduce(into: initialParameters) { emailParameters, queryItem in
            guard let value = queryItem.value else {
                return
            }
            switch queryItem.name {
            case "to":
                emailParameters.toEmails += splitEmail(value)
            case "cc":
                emailParameters.ccEmails += splitEmail(value)
            case "bcc":
                emailParameters.bccEmails += splitEmail(value)
            case "subject" where emailParameters.subject == nil:
                emailParameters.subject = value
            case "body" where emailParameters.body == nil:
                emailParameters.body = value
            default:
                break
            }
        }
        self.init(
            toEmails: emailParameters.toEmails,
            ccEmails: emailParameters.ccEmails,
            bccEmails: emailParameters.bccEmails,
            subject: emailParameters.subject,
            body: emailParameters.body,
            validateEmail: validateEmail
        )
    }
}
```

Once included in your app, parsing `mailto` links become as simple as:

```swift
let mailToURL: URL(string: "mailto:test@example.com")!
if let emailParameters = EmailParameters(url: url) {
  // You can then access each of `emailParameters`'s fields
  // emailParameters.toEmails is guaranteed to have a non-empty email address (i.e accessing `emailParameters.toEmails[0]` will never crash)
  // Note it doesn't perform email validation by default, but you can specify
  // a custom `validateEmail` closure if need be in the `EmailParameters` initializer above
}
```

I've also created a gist that extends on this with more feature, available [here](https://gist.github.com/stephanecopin/9b5da27e06f1f59e07630502d555ed46) (this was specifically made to nicely support links in embedded HTML & Markdown content).

Comment: `emails.map{$0.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)}.filter(validateEmail)`

Comment: @LeoDabus Indeed! Thank you, that's what reviews are for. I had something else at first and just updated the code without refactoring. Edited the answer & gist.